# Call a JavaScript function across browser tabs

Tags: javascript

I have two browser tabs, tab1 and tab2.

I have a function called execute in tab1, which I would like to call from the page in tab2.

Is that possible and if so how?

Comment: You can do that now with localStorage storage event or with library that use that event.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

JavaScript ***can not*** do cross-tab scripting in the browser (it is a security risk).

***If however*** the second tab was opened from a `window.open()` call, and the browsers settings were set up such that new popup windows open in a new tab instead -- *then **yes***, "tab1" can talk to "tab2".

The first tab/window is called the `opener` and thus the new tab can call functions on the opener using this format:

```
opener.doSomething();
```

Likewise, the opener can call functions on the new tab/popup, by using the variable it created when creating the popup window.

```
var myPopup = window.open(url, name, features);
myPopup.doStuffOnPopup();
```

Comment: It is actually possible to do "cross-tab scripting" using [window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) or [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) to send messages between tabs.

Comment: @AndersonGreen, some people just get off on saying “you can’t”, “it can’t be done”.  Thanks for actually providing something of use given the question.

Comment: @AndersonGreen and Adrian M. - we should add an answer on how to do this with postMessage() / Broadcast Channel. When my answer was written in 2010, IE8 was Microsoft's latest browser, Chrome was on v4.1, Firefox <5? etc. **so at the time, it wasn't possible**. Feel free to add an answer with a modern solution, or let me know if you'd like me to add one.

Answer (score 2):

There's a tiny open-source component to sync/lock/call code in multiple tabs that allows you send messages between tabs (DISCLAIMER: I'm one of the contributors!)

https://github.com/jitbit/TabUtils

That can be called like this:

```
TabUtils.BroadcastMessageToAllTabs("messageName", data);
```

And then in another tab:

```
TabUtils.OnBroadcastMessage("messageName", function (data) {
    //do something
});
```

It is based on the `onstorage` event, you can simply modify the code for you need, it's very simple.

Comment: What web browsers (incl. versions) does it support?

Comment: @PeterMortensen any browser that supports localStorage

Answer (score 0):

You should show your HTML in the first place, but I assume your tab has a link, and you could it do like this:

```
<a href="some-path" id="tab2">Tab 2</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#tab2').click(function(){
  // Your function code here

  // Prevent the default action
  return false;
})
```

Comment: I think he meant real tabs, not pseudo tabs

Answer (score 0):

You can pass JavaScript function references as arguments to other functions (be wary of object execution contexts).

So while initializing "tab2", you could send in the function reference of *execute* of "tab1", to "tab2".

Comment: my basic quetiosn is how to call a fucation in other window or other tab?

Comment: I am not aware of a way to do that !
Isnt the javascript window object the parent-most object that we have at our disposal? How can you access the code in another window ?! (Violates the very principle of how a browser works, in my understanding)
Can you explain your need a little more, I may be able to suggest a workaround .

Answer (score 0):

With a browser extension that can be done, you target your desired tabs and use the chrome.scripting API

For a general purpose solution as a DevTools you can use: https://github.com/devidw/tabgod (disclaimer I am the author)