# Call function after page was loaded in new tab

Tags: javascript, html

After clicking on the button i need to open some link in new tab, and than after the page would be loaded, I need to programmatically perform some actions on this page (like clicking on proper GUI elements etc).

For example this code should open in new tab http://stackoverflow.com and after that click on "Tags":

```
<button type=\"button\"
    onclick="window.open('http://stackoverflow.com', '_blank');
    document.getElementById('nav-tags').click();">Click Me!
</button>
```

but the function `document.getElementById('nav-tags').click()` does not call.

Comment: there is no way of doing this (for security reasons) but what you could do is load stackoverflow.com/tags

Comment: It's just example with stackoverflow.com . These needs for SPA (single page application) website

Comment: If SPA is made with angular, you can still open direct url. Other ways of doing this are: using cookies to store/load information between tabs or local storage. But they must be in same domain/have same parent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a JavaScript function across browser tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614520/call-a-javascript-function-across-browser-tabs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in comment, there is no way to directly communicate between tabs/windows.

There are way around this however:

1. when opening another tab, send data you need in url (like i suggested in comments stackoveflow.com/tags)
2. communicate using cookies (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4079423/3600886)
3. communicate using local storage (http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) - there is a library for that: https://github.com/diy/intercom.js/

If your usage is to just show some data upon page load, I'd say go with first option, it will work across all browsers, free of any other restrictions.

With other options you will need pages to be on same domain or have same parent window, plus local storage is not supported by older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Create the tab from JavaScript and you can access the tab with JavaScript and place a onload function

```
var w = window.open();
w.onload = function(){

};
```

You can also put the onload function in the tab:

```
window.onload = function(){
}
```

Comment: Tried to do this with a simple console.log as the function, but it did not work. The message wasnt logged on either of the websites. I used your first example with a console.log() in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your JS in .ready event. So it will be called when whole page DOM is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      document.getElementById('nav-tags').click();
});
```