# Execute JavaScript on all pages?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I know that if I want to manually execute a javascript code on one page, I can open up the page's console and execute it there. But what if I want to execute the same javascript for all opened pages ? Any quicker way to do this, instead of having to do it manually for each page (can be a problem if you have 30+ tabs opened) ?

Comment: I suggest you to read the first answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614520/call-a-javascript-function-across-browser-tabs