# Javascript performing click() in another Chrome tab using developer console

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-console

I'm using Google Chrome Dev Console to execute this script:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function checkbtn(btn) {
    if (btn.singleNodeValue != null) {
        console.log('Success!')
        btn.singleNodeValue.click();
        throw new Error();
    } else {
        console.log('button not here yet - next button');
    };
}

function check() {
    url = window.location.href;
    var newwindow = window.open(url, 'tab2');
    //sleep 250ms
    await sleep(250);
    var newwindow2 = window.open(url, 'tab3');
    //sleep 250ms
    await sleep(250);
    var newwindow3 = window.open(url, 'tab4');
    var loginbtn;
    while (true) {
        loginbtn = newwindow.document.evaluate("//*[text()='5544']/../../td[@class='action']/form/input[@type='submit' and not(@disabled)]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
        console.log('trying button 1');
        checkbtn(loginbtn);
        loginbtn = newwindow2.document.evaluate("//*[text()='5544']/../../td[@class='action']/form/input[@type='submit' and not(@disabled)]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
        console.log('trying button 2');
        checkbtn(loginbtn);
        loginbtn = newwindow3.document.evaluate("//*[text()='5544']/../../td[@class='action']/form/input[@type='submit' and not(@disabled)]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
        console.log('trying button 3');
        checkbtn(loginbtn);     
    };
};
```

However, this leads to nothing but the click being performed in the currently active tab, in which's console I post the code. Is there a way to make the Click happen in e.g. the third tab or is this impossible because of security reasons?

EDIT:
As of duplication reasons to this: [Call a javascript function across browser tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614520/call-a-javascript-function-across-browser-tabs):
The given post doesn't clarify if the code is ran from the browser console. I want to know if there is any way that I could manipulate the other tab (locally) to click a button.
Also: if not possible: is it possible with an extension?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a JavaScript function across browser tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614520/call-a-javascript-function-across-browser-tabs)

Comment: It is no duplicate in my opinion, as I am asking if I can execute Javascript in the other tab or not. The Post given states that Cross-Tab-Scripting is impossible - but still if I'd be able to manipulate the source-code of the other tab and then call the scripted function, it is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using a browser extension. You could have a content script file injected in all tabs to manipulate the DOM and a background script to query the desired tabs.
This option would require querying tabs in background and then sending messages to the content script in order to execute the JS code.

Or you could use `chrome.tabs.query` and `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, which are available only in the background context, thus you wouldn't need to use content scripts as injected files.

Comment: So you would suggest running an extension that injects an event-like script. Is it possible to call them then like:
var myPopup = window.open(url, name, features);
myPopup.doStuffOnPopup(button);

Giving them the direct button to click on?

Comment: If you know all the button selectors you're looking for, then you can query the tab by url or id in background and send a message to the content script to execute some function that you can put in a object inside the window object.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using an extension that adds function checkbtn() to the new tab. I then am calling it over console using

`newwindow.checkbtn(args)`

However, this seems to be a little too complicated and since I don't need to handle the call over a third party library like Selenium, this seems to be a little overkill and thus, I am working on making the whole script being executed by the extension.