# How can i provoke a revaluation of a react component when user copies something on their ClipBoard?

Tags: reactjs, clipboard.js

I am trying to build a component with some validations depending on user's clipboard.

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function useCopiedFromClipboard() {
  const [copiedData, setCopiedData] = useState<string>('')

    navigator.clipboard
      .readText()
      .then((text) => {
        setCopiedData(text)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Failed to read clipboard contents: ', err)
      })

  return { copiedData }
}
```

So what I really want to do is use this hook inside a component.

```js
import React from 'react'

export default function MyComponent() {
  const {copiedData} = useCopiedFromClipboard()
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('Run')
  },[copiedData])
  
  return (
    <></>
  )
}
```

I am expecting this useEffect to run everytime the user copies something to their clipboard. But this is not working.

Does anyone have any idea of how to implement this one ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you're only getting the value of the clipboard once, when you initialize the `useCopiedFromClipboard` hook for the first time. It does not **'listen'** for more clipboard events.

We can solve this by using a `useEffect` where we setup a listener on the `copy` event. When the event first we manually get the selected text in the document and set that value to the users clipboard. Then we can update the state with the same value.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useCopiedFromClipboard() {
  const [copiedData, setCopiedData] = useState<string>("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleCopy = (e: ClipboardEvent) => {
      const selection = document.getSelection() ?? "";
      const data = selection.toString();
      e.clipboardData?.setData("text/plain", data);
      setCopiedData(data);
    };

    document.addEventListener("copy", handleCopy);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("copy", handleCopy);
    };
  }, []);

  const onCopy = (text: string) => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
    setCopiedData(text);
  };

  return { copiedData, onCopy };
}
```

We can use `onCopy` as follows

```js
const { copiedData, onCopy } = useCopiedFromClipboard();

return (
  <>
    <button onClick={() => onCopy("something")}>copy</button>
    {copiedData && <p>{copiedData}</p>}
  </>
);
```

You can add some try catch as you wish, this should cover the bare logic.

Comment: That partially seems to work. But now I have a second problem. This event listener works when i ctr+c a text, but it doesnt work when i press a btn that i have created, that copies in the clipboard some text i pass through. 
I am using a library for that called 'react-copy-to-clipboard'.
Do you have any idea for that?

Comment: Some how when I use a button that triggers a function like:

function copy(text: string) {
  return window.navigator.clipboard.writeText(text)
}

This is not binded to ur proposed code

Comment: Upssss and it doesnt work between different tabs... I am asking too much right ?

Comment: You could add a extra function to this hook which allows you to do the `navigator.clipboard.writeText()` and also updates the state. As for the different tabs, it's **not possible**, see [Call a JavaScript function across browser tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614520/call-a-javascript-function-across-browser-tabs)

Comment: @KonstantinosAlexis I've updated my answer to both capture the user's **Ctrl+c** and a **onCopy** function to execute from e.g. a button

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I chose for my problem.
Its not that I love it but at least it works between different tabs, and thats super important for my application.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function useCopiedFromClipboard() {
  const [copiedData, setCopiedData] = useState<string>('')

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(async function () {
      if (await document.hasFocus()) {
        if (location.protocol === 'https:') {
          navigator.clipboard.readText().then((text) => {
            setCopiedData(text)
          })
        } else {
          clearInterval(timer)
        }
      }
    }, 1000)
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])

  return { copiedData }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function useCopiedFromClipboard() {
  const [copiedData, setCopiedData] = useState<string>('')

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClipboardChange = () => {
      navigator.clipboard
        .readText()
        .then((text) => {
          setCopiedData(text)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error('Failed to read clipboard contents: ', err)
        })
    }

    document.addEventListener('paste', handleClipboardChange)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('paste', handleClipboardChange)
    }
  }, [])

  return { copiedData }
}
```

Hope this helps you